"Not a valid calendar for the given culter" whilst launching program with Wine
So I have a little problem.
I am trying to Launch a windows program (Bime.exe) which uses ".NET 4.8" and "EITcommon6" as a base.
It works fine when I launch it on any windows version above win7 but when I try to launch it via Wine on Arch, it gives me the "Not a valid calendar for the given culter"  Error.
Here's the full Error message

I tried changing the globalization values with the makeshift regEdit on Wine but it didn't seem to work.
any ideas how I can fix this?
